# Show that $f$ has a stationary point at $(0, 0)$ for every $k ∈ R$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Show that $f$ has a stationary point at $(0,0)$ for every $k ∈ R$.
$f(x,y) = x^2 + kxy + y^2$
I know that the definition of a stationary point is when the gradient is $0$ so local maximum or local min or point of inflection.
But unsure how to show that the point is stationary at $(0,0)$ for every $k ∈ R$.

Comment: Points of inflection are not necessarily stationary points. Consider sine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\nabla f = (f_x,f_y) = (2x+ky,2y+kx) = (0,0)$ at $(x,y) = (0,0)$. This concludes the claim.

Comment: it is concluded because  $2(0)+k(0)=0$ and $ 2(0)+k(0)=0$ correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.